# Why does less change order of output?

Tags: c, shell, unix, terminal

I am running a python script which produces certain output when I run it in verbose mode. When I pipe the output to the less utility, the output is in a different order. For reference, the script is, if not exactly, very nearly this:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/change-svn-wc-format.py

Specifically, I get the "Data for the following field(s)" message and when I run it without piping the output to less, this message appears last. When I pipe the output to less, the output mysteriously appears first.

Can anybody explain this?

I have determined that the error message goes to stderr while the verbose messages go to stdout. However, even when I do:

```
./svnfixversion ./ 1.5 --verbose 2>&1 | less
```

the output is different from when I just leave off the | less. If the stderr is getting redirected to stdout, shouldn't less preserve the order?

Comment: `less` does preserve the order it receives; however, there's no guarantee how the shell is interleaving standard error and standard output when writing to the pipe in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run:

```
./svnfixversion ./ 1.5 --verbose
```

its `stdout` is line buffered, `stderr` is non-buffered.

In:

```
./svnfixversion ./ 1.5 --verbose 2>&1 | less
```

its `stdout` is fully buffered, `stderr` is non-buffered.

The buffering mode of `./svnfixversion` `FILE* stdout` is what makes the output different in these two cases.

If you want the second output to be identical to the first one, set `stdout` buffering mode to line buffered with `stdbuf` application:

```
stdbuf --output=L ./svnfixversion ./ 1.5 --verbose 2>&1 | less
```

In modern `bash` you can replace `2>&1 |` with shorter `|&`.

---

What happens under the hood, is that at program start before `main()` is called `glibc` calls [`isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) to determine whether `stdout` is connected to a terminal. If so, `stdout` is line buffered, otherwise full buffered. `stderr` is always unbuffered.

Comment: I knew stderr had no buffering, but I had never heard of line buffered vs fully buffered... thanks so much!